# Sencha touch slicing store data

Tags: json

I'm trying to slice store data with different roots to different grids but im getting error "Cannot read property "jsonData" of undefined"
Below is my code:

var store1 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({ url: 'myurl', root: 'root1', fields: ['field1', 'field2'] });

var store2 = new Ext.data.JsonStore({ url: 'myurl', root: 'root2', fields: ['field1', 'field2'] });

store1.load({ callback: function(){ store2.loadData(store1.reader.jsonData); } });

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that reader is not directly accessible from store.

Try using store.getProxy().getReader();

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store